# Redirect specific link for logged in users only to specific URL

Tags: wp-redirect

i have a custom Woocommerce link that adds a product to the cart and redirects user to the account page:

```
account/?add-to-cart=15169
```

I'd like this link to redirect only logged-in users to some specific URL and all the other users to the Account page

**Right now:**

**Not Logged in users** redirect to create an account page, that is fine.

**Logged in users** redirect to Account page

**Question:** Is there a way to redirect only logged-in users to a specific url for this specific link rather than the account page?

**I have tried:**

```
//redirect logged-in users from Account page id=90 to specific page id=15498
function my_logged_in_redirect() {

if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 90 ) )
{
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( 15498 ) );
    die;
}

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_logged_in_redirect' );
```

that works but then the account page is actually not accessible from logged-in users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check the query string and redirect if query string matches the product id.

```
function my_logged_in_redirect() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 90 ) && $_GET['add-to-cart'] == 15169 ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( 15498 ) );
        die;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_logged_in_redirect' );
```

Comment: you can accept this answer if it worked for you, so another user with same questions can use it as reference :)

Comment: What is the difference between using `die` and using `exit(wp_redirect(get_permalink(...)))` ?